# Powershell Screen Scraping - Get displayed text only

Tags: powershell, screen-scraping

I have URL from which I can quickly get the content I require if I just copy the page as displayed in browser and paste that into notepad.  Is there a way to get the text only from a URL in PowerShell?

Yes I possibly could dissect the page using formal screen scraping, but I would need to determine where in the DOM the required data is. This way is simpler if I can get it to work.

My code for parsing the copied text. Assumes a specific first line, and a heading line before the required line.

```
    $expectFirstLine = <First line>
    $lineBeforeTargeLine = <LineBefore>
        $content = Get-Clipboard
        if (-not (([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($content)) ))
        {
            $lines = $content -split '\n'
            if ($lines.Length -gt 0)
            {
                if ($lines[0] -eq $expectFirstLine)
                {
                    $index = $lines.Indexof($lineBeforeTargeLine)
                    if ($index -ne -1)
                    {
                        $target = $lines[$index+1]
                        $target= $target.Trim()
                        write-host "Found Target: $target"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: "as displayed in browser"  are you talking about the content generated or the view source?  Content generation could be done in frames, JavaScript, and other methods that might not be so easy to grab in PowerShell as it displays to the end user.  Can you elaborate?  Also do you have any code you've tried in PowerShell for us to look at?

Comment: yes, there is a way. _of course there is a way to do it_. [*grin*] HOWEVER, you will need to show the target url, what you want from that url, and your current code before anyone can help you with your problem.

Comment: I can't give the URL as its private but I can use this page as an example. Start with the mouse cursor to the left of stackoverflow icon top left and drag down to [Add Comment] button. Right click the selected text. That is what I want,

Comment: I've tried $web = Invoke-WebRequest –Uri <My url>

You then can get, for example, all links on the page from the link property ie $web.Links  
Hoping there is a property that will give me what I want.

Comment: I am also having problems, I think, with a site that needs to browsed with the later version of Edge (Chromium version). Invoke-WebRequest  always comes back with the login  page regardless of my login status on the device and whatever credentials I supply.  The page is an Azure IoT Central App page.